# Pair/Bind an array with a dynamic number of entry fields in python/tkinter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tkinter

I'm currently relearning how to program in Python.
What I have so far is a text file loaded in, it split into a 2D NumPy array from which I derive how many entry fields are needed to be able to load the strings in, this works just fine.

What I would like to do is pair those entry fields with the array so I can have a button that will update the array so I can refresh the window adding or removing entry fields depending on whether the fields are populated or not. If this isn't possible, is there another way around this?
Thanks in Advance!

```
from tkinter import *
import math as m
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt

#Import Todo List
lines = loadtxt("Todofile.txt", dtype="object", delimiter="\n")
TDHead=np.array(lines[0::2])
TDSub=np.array(lines[1::2])
length=len(TDHead)
TDFull=np.empty((length,2), dtype="object")

#Sort Todo list into Arrays (Done to make editing easier when placed in GUI)
count=0
while count != length:
    TDFull[count,0]=TDHead[count]
    TDFull[count,1]=TDSub[count]
    count +=1

root = Tk()
root.title("Todo List")
TDframe=Frame(root)
TDframe.pack()

a=0
for x in range (length):
    EntryHead = Entry(TDframe, width=50)
    SLabel = Label(TDframe, text="Title: ")
    SLabel.grid(row=a, column=0)
    EntryHead.grid(row=a, column=1, pady=0,padx=5)
    EntryHead.insert(0,TDFull[x,0])
    EntrySub = Entry(TDframe, width=50)
    SLabel = Label(TDframe, text="Description: ")
    SLabel.grid(row=a+1, column=0)
    EntrySub.grid(row=a+1,column=1, pady=0,padx=5)
    EntrySub.insert(0,TDFull[x,1])
    a=a+3
UIHID=Label(TDframe, text="Enter New Task: ") .grid(row= a,column=0)
UIH= Entry(TDframe, width=50) .grid(row=a, column=1)
UISID=Label(TDframe, text="Describe Task: ") .grid(row= a+1, column=0)
UIS= Entry(TDframe, width=50) .grid(row= a+1, column=1)
UIB= Button(TDframe, text="Add New Item" command=resort) .grid(column=0)

def resort():
    
    pass

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could you explain what u want, in terms of code?

Comment: It's 2 dimensional todo list read in from a text file, the gui to display an entry field for each item on the list when the button is pressed it checks the fields for input and refresh the number of entry field according, depending whether something has been added or not.

Comment: okay, so what is the problem now?